# Pandas combine two columns into one and exclude NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 5k x 2 column dataframe called "both". 
I want to create a new 5k x 1 DataFrame or column (doesn't matter) by replacing any NaN value in one column with the value of the adjacent column.

ex:

```
    Gains  Loss
0    NaN   NaN
1    NaN -0.17
2    NaN -0.13
3    NaN -0.75
4    NaN -0.17
5    NaN -0.99
6   1.06   NaN
7    NaN -1.29
8    NaN -0.42
9   0.14  NaN
```

so for example, I need to swap the NaNs in the first column in rows 1 through 5 with the values in the same rows, in second column to get a new df of the following form:

```
    Change  
0     NaN  
1    -0.17 
2    -0.13  
3    -0.75 
4    -0.17  
5    -0.99  
6    1.06
```

how do I tell python to do this??

Comment: what is both are not NaN.. so I guess it doesn't exist?

Comment: Something like this?
`both.Price.fillna(both.price, inplace=True)`
Then you can delete the column that you do not need `both.drop(['price'], axis=1)`

Comment: @XXavier: I updated my example, it was misleading to have two columns named the same. Can you please adjust your code so I know which operations to perform on which columns?

Comment: Try this `both.Loss.fillna(both.Gains, inplace=True)`

Comment: @RahelMiz , i will post this as answer so you can accept it as answer?

Answer (score 5):

You may fill the `NaN` values with zeroes and then simply add your columns:

```
both["Change"] = both["Gains"].fillna(0) + both["Loss"].fillna(0)
```

Then — if you need it — you may return the resulting zeroes back to `NaN`s:

```
both["Change"].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

The result:

> ```
>     Gains      Loss  Change
> 0     NaN       NaN     NaN
> 1     NaN     -0.17   -0.17
> 2     NaN     -0.13   -0.13
> 3     NaN     -0.75   -0.75
> 4     NaN     -0.17   -0.17
> 5     NaN     -0.99   -0.99
> 6    1.06       NaN    1.06
> 7     NaN     -1.29   -1.29
> 8     NaN     -0.42   -0.42
> 9    0.14       NaN    0.14
> ```

Finally, if you want to get rid of your original columns, you may drop them:

```
both.drop(columns=["Gains", "Loss"], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. One is using the loc property:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Price1': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,
                              np.nan,np.nan,1.06,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'Price2': [np.nan,-0.17,-0.13,-0.75,-0.17,
                              -0.99,np.nan,-1.29,-0.42]})

df.loc[df['Price1'].isnull(), 'Price1'] = df['Price2']
df = df.loc[:6,'Price1']

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Price1
0     NaN
1   -0.17
2   -0.13
3   -0.75
4   -0.17
5   -0.99
6    1.06
```

You can see more complex recipes in the [Cookbook](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/cookbook.html#cookbook)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, we can filter for null values and just sum the columns to make your new dataframe.

```
cols = ['Gains','Loss']

s = df.isnull().cumsum(axis=1).eq(len(df.columns)).any(axis=1)
# add df[cols].isnull() if you only want to measure the price columns for nulls.

df['prices'] = df[cols].loc[~s].sum(axis=1)

df = df.drop(cols,axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df)

   prices
0     NaN
1   -0.17
2   -0.13
3   -0.75
4   -0.17
5   -0.99
6    1.06
7   -1.29
8   -0.42
```

Comment: I updated my example,  it was misleading to have two columns named the same. Can you please adjust your code so I know which operations to perform on which columns?

Comment: @RahelMiz done, it's a simple task that can be done any number of ways.